# Transforming compass direction output

Tags: java, trigonometry, compass-geolocation

I have directional outputs which are both flipped and + - as appose to genuine compass outputs. I want to convert these using math to give me the correct output. I am pretty sure this can be done using trigonometric functions, i would welcome any advice i have drawn a quick sketch excuse the rough jotting.
[Left the current situation on the right the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4hOc.png)

I hope that makes sense. North and south are flipped, if they were flipped back then we would have north to east positive 0-180, north to west negative 0-(-180), however i need it flipped and represented as normal compass headings,

Comment: So the range of your input is -180...180?

Comment: … and the question is?

Comment: So at the moment imagine you have a phone held flat with the top of the phone pointing at N which gives 0 or 360 reading, i want to have that flipped so when the top of the phone is pointed at S it give 0 or 360. However when the phone is pointed at N currently if the phone is rotated clockwise the output is -->45-->90-->135-->180 if rotated anticlockwise the output is -->(-45)-->(-90)-->(-135)-->(-180). so to sum up i require the behaviour to be phone pointed at S = 0 or 360 rotated clockwise -->90.....-->180.....>270... back to 0 or 360.

Comment: The question is how do i transform the current behaviour to the behaviour/outputs i require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the image, it looks like simply `newAngle = oldAngle+180` (assuming input of -180...180).

Comment: You are absolutely correct, i was trying this, however i had a bracket out of place in the code so it wasn't giving the results i expected, this was why i was so confused. Apologies for the simple question